# Запуск программы

Tags: javascript

Киньте пример пожалуйста, как запустить программу на клиентской машине используя javascript, и вообще можно ли так??? вроде телеграмм таким образом запускает десктопную версию. Спасибо)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome#answer-37601807

Если кратко, то ассоциация настраивается определенного протокола с вашим приложением на уровне ОС и на уровне браузера.